# WordPress: register_activation_hook()

Tags: wordpress

Hi I am trying to create table if not exist on plugin activation using wordpress register_activation_hook() function.

Code is working fine when I place it in plugin main file (where we define the plugin meta) but when I tried to use it in other file in sub directory it doesn't working. I have try to change `register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'my_medias_db');` to `register_activation_hook(to_plugin_root_path, 'my_medias_db');` to plugin root path but still not working. any idea?

**Here is the code**

```
function my_medias_db() {
    require_once( ABSPATH . '/wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
    global $wpdb;
    $db_table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'my_medias';
    if( $wpdb->get_var( "SHOW TABLES LIKE '$db_table_name'" ) != $db_table_name ) {
        if ( ! empty( $wpdb->charset ) )
            $charset_collate = "DEFAULT CHARACTER SET $wpdb->charset";
        if ( ! empty( $wpdb->collate ) )
            $charset_collate .= " COLLATE $wpdb->collate";

        $sql = "CREATE TABLE " . $db_table_name . " (
            `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            `post_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
            `image_name` text NOT NULL,
            `status` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
            PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
        ) $charset_collate;";
        dbDelta( $sql );
    }
}
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'my_medias_db');
```

Answer (score 0):

is the code above in the main plugin index file?

If its not, that's your problem.  If you take a look at the wp code, the activation_hook calls rely on the $file parameter being the plugin index file, so if you're calling register_activation_hook from another file try something like this (This is an OO example)

...snip...

```
    $strPluginFilename = $this->getMainPluginFilename();
    // rcarver - the activation hook calls rely on the file name being the plugin index!
    register_activation_hook($strPluginFilename, array($this, 'baseActivate') );
    register_deactivation_hook($strPluginFilename, array($this, 'baseDeactivate') );
```

...snip...

```
protected function getMainPluginFilename() {
    // eg. /some/place/wp-content/plugins/my_cool_plugin/pluginbase.php will
    // result in the base file name of  "my_cool_plugin.php"
    // NOTE: THIS ONLY WORKS IF THE CURRENT FILE IS IN THE SAME DIRECTORY
    //       AS THE MAIN PLUGIN FILE!
    return dirname(__FILE__) . '/' . basename(dirname(__FILE__)) . '.php';
}
```

...snip...